# Mobile web architecture using angularJS

Tags: angularjs, architecture, mobile-website, directory-structure, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing a responsive mobile web app to support maximum devices ( iPhone/Android/windows .. handsets/tablets ).What I am planning is that, extending same architecture, I can build Hybrid Apps.

From a angular architecture point of view,  I am thinking to have a global controller which would decide a app type ( hybrid/web or device type)  and pass the request & invoke the appropriate template from desired view ( assuming view is different for these devices)

I would like to know best practices in implementing such architecture? appreciate for your quick help.

Thank you

Comment: You probably want a service/factory object for global configurations instead of an overall controller, otherwise your $scope is going to be littered with objects and you might as well be defining variables on window.

Comment: ok. Thank you for your suggestion. That means this factory will be active to setup app type, only for one time throughout the session.  I followed "yeoman" to have clean directory structure but as I mentioned the requirement , could any one suggest me appropriate directory structure?